# Why the child row doesn't open? in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to attached child rows to a parent row in DataTable. The idea for this is to show additional information for fields date_arrival and date_departure. I'm following the DataTables examples Child rows (show extra / detailed information) (https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) from the documentation but I can't figure out what I'm missing. The only difference is that I take the data from API and save it to the database first. If someone is able to help will be really appreciated.

This is the playground that I prepared: http://live.datatables.net/jadorolu/2/edit

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple, you table has the id `datatable` not `example`

So this line

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
```

needs to be

```
$('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
```

You can see it work [here](http://live.datatables.net/jadorolu/5/watch?output)